# jqgrid not showing search custom fields

Tags: jqgrid

I am migrating code from jqgrid 4 to jqgrid 5.0.0 and cannot seem to fix this issue.
in jqgrid 5.0.0 do we still need to use **searchoptions : {sopt** ?

```
colModel:[
        {
            name:'col_id',
            key:false,
            index:'col_id',
            width:40,
            searchoptions: {sopt: ['bw','eq','ne','lt','le','gt','ge','ew','cn']},
            editable:false,
            edittype:'custom',
            editoptions:{custom_element:disabledelem, custom_value:elemvalue},
            formatter:customFormatter
        },
```

[image: Not seeing search filters popup]

I checked the source code for
jquery.jqGrid.5.0.0.js

and I cannot see any way this.oper will have a value with the way I am using this. The online examples for jqgrid is not very clear.

```
        $.each(that.p.ops, function() { aoprs.push(this.oper); });
        for ( i = 0; i < op.length; i++) {
            ina = $.inArray(op[i],aoprs);
            if(ina !== -1) {
                selected = rule.op === that.p.ops[ina].oper ? " selected='selected'" : "";
                str += "<option value='"+that.p.ops[ina].oper+"'"+selected+">"+that.p.ops[ina].text+"</option>";
            }
        }
```

Comment: Could you verify whether the problem exists in [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) 4.10.0? You need just change the URLs to described in [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs).

Comment: This works great in version 4.10.0.

Comment: Then it seems be a bug in [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) 5.0.0, which you use. [Free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) is the fork of jqGrid which I develop after changing of license agreement and renaming jqGrid to Guriddo jqGrid JS (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?p=1438)). You can consider to change to free jqGrid.

Comment: I posted the same information as the answer, because other people could have the same problem. The searching engine can't index the comments good enough. it interprets there not as the solution of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be a bug in [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) 5.0.0, which you use. I recommend you to try the same code with [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) 4.10.0. You need just change the URLs to described in [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs). Free jqGrid is the fork of jqGrid, which I develop after changing of license agreement and renaming jqGrid to Guriddo jqGrid JS (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?p=1438)). You can consider to migrate to free jqGrid if the code works in the fork.

Comment: I tried jqGrid JS 5.0.1 and this works correctly is 5.0.1

Comment: @RubenBenjamin: It could be important for other users! It seems, it was really a bug.